# What are the problems in the following code？

Tags: c++

I have tow code about the the question [Binary Tree Pruning](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-pruning/).
this is a wrong code

```
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* pruneTree(TreeNode* root) {
        if(root == NULL)
            return NULL;
        if((root->left = pruneTree(root->left)) == NULL &&
           (root->right = pruneTree(root->right)) == NULL){
            if(root->val == 0){
                delete root;
                return NULL;
            }       
        }
        return root;
    }
};
```

this is my passed code

```
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* pruneTree(TreeNode* root) {
        if(root == NULL)
            return NULL;
        root->left = pruneTree(root->left);
        root->right = pruneTree(root->right);
        if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL){
            if(root->val == 0){
                delete root;
                return NULL;
            }       
        }
        return root;
    }
};
```

I want to know what cause the difference between the two programs

Comment: The first one doesn't prune right if left is NULL

Comment: Read about short-circuiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second code, it is guaranteed that both `pruneTree(root->left)` and `pruneTree(root->right)` are called, because those are two separate expressions.

```
root->left = pruneTree(root->left);
root->right = pruneTree(root->right);
```

In the first code you have:

```
(root->left = pruneTree(root->left)) == NULL &&
           (root->right = pruneTree(root->right)) == NULL
```

The difference here is that `pruneTree(root->left)` and `pruneTree(root->right)` are in one expression, so they might (and this case the do) depend on each other.

If `(root->left = pruneTree(root->left)) == NULL` evaluates to `false` then the parte after the `&&` does not need to be evaluated, because the complete expression can't become true anymore.